# How to display n record per page, but no break at the end if the number of records > 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, report, formula, page-numbering

I use visual studio 2010 with Crystal Report, and I'm created a report and look like example:

[image: How to display n record per page, but no break at the end]

My problem is when RecordNumber > 8, page break and display as example:
[image: How to display n record per page, but no break at the end]

I want to after **the number of records** > 8 and **end of page** then page will be broken. 
I search some of code:

```
RecordNumber mod 8 = 0 and not OnLastRecord
```

and

```
 if Remainder (RecordNumber, 6) = 0 then true else false
```

But can't apply with my case

Comment: So you have two subreports in a main report. Are the subreports in the same section on the main report?

Comment: Yes, exactly have you anything ideas

Comment: Create two separate sections and put each subreport in their own section. Then try either one of your formulas.

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Where are you applying the formulas, in the main report or subreports? The subreports produce the data, so your formatting needs to happen there.

Comment: I apply it in subreports. I want it doesn't break page at the end of sub report. But doesn't work!

Comment: Do you have a example with my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work something very stupid, but it's resovled with my case. I fake a view report viewer and code all function for it with vb.net.